# Decompile large function in IDA

Tags: decompilation, hexrays

I'm working on a crack me, specifically: [jaunsacco's DragonCrack](https://crackmes.one/crackme/5d3052e133c5d444ad3017b9) and the first thing I've gotten stuck on is that the program is built mostly as a enormous main function. After attempting to decompile I get the error:

> Decompilation failure:
>   11E1640: too big function

I've increased my max function size for decompilation to 512K (defaults at 64), the main function is approx. 400K. But this is too much processing and IDA froze for at least 5 minutes before I gave up.

Is there an alternative approach to decompiling a large (400K) function using Hex-Rays decompiler? Maybe partial decompilation, or non-default decompiler configuration.

*IDA: Version 7.2.181105*

*Hex-Rays Decompiler: v7.0.0.170914*

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. So you're working with the Hex-Rays decompiler plugin, right? It'd be good if you would state both the IDA and Hex-Rays versions, so there is a chance we can better help. Alternatively you could send an email to the Hex-Rays support. In the past they were generally very helpful whenever I ran into an issue.

Comment: From my experience, latest versions of IDA fix those problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can give https://retdec.com/idaplugin/ a try. I've heard it can decompile larger functions without much error.

According to them it supports decompiling a whole binary file. So it possibly could decompile this function without much hesitation. Although I can't promise anything.

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The question is too old, but I'll answer it anyway, maybe it'll be useful for someone else.

You can change the MAX_FUNCSIZE variable in the \IDA\cfg\hexrays.cfg

The default is 64, put a bigger number. For example, I'm using 4096

Reference:
https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/config.shtml

Comment: If you read the question properly, you will note that I have already tried this.

Comment: Maybe it was not enough. Now I have 16384. It just a thought, I tried and it worked for me and I shared the results. also after changes you need to restart IDA

Comment: As I said, please read the question properly. I set mine to 512K. Thats 512000. Thats 31.25 larger than what you're suggesting. It froze my IDA because the function seems to be too large for the decompiler.

Comment: Ok, understood. I just shared a solution I used with exactly the same error and worked for me. If you'll find some useful things, please let us know via this post reply